# rest service works when deployed in Eclipse but not in Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, spring, rest, tomcat, xmlhttprequest

I implemented rest web services with Spring. When I deployed it in Eclipse as a Spring Boot Application, it works. However when I deployed it in Tomcat 7 on the same machine, it does not work. The error message is as follows:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/ristoreService/oauth/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My CORS filter looks like this:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, "
                + "Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
```

If I comment out `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");`, I still get the same error. It wouldn't work without this line even if I deploy in Eclipse. Why does it act differently being deployed under different environment on the same ip?

EDIT:
I tested the url `http://localhost:8080/ristoreService/oauth/token`with rest client tester "CocoaRestClient" and got 404.  So I made up a url which apparently does not exist `http://localhost:8080/xxxxx` and run it in UI (angularjs) and again got the CORS error. I think the error is kind of misleading, it is after all a 404. But why does it complain not found when the war was deployed successfully with the name ristoreService.war under webapps in Tomcat?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

Comment: @Ulises Mentioned in my post `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [How to deploy Spring Boot application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html), I have to make main application to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`. Once I added that, it works.

Comment: Ok, yeah, I took that for granted, I guess I could have asked.

Comment: Can you share this solution via git please if it's not a secret?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a FilterRegistrationBean. Looks like this in Java Config:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean authorizationFilter(){
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegBean.setFilter(authorizationFilter);
    List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
    urlPatterns.add("/v1/*");
    filterRegBean.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
    return filterRegBean;
}
```

Any reason why you're not using Spring Boot's CORS capabilities? It's already supported out of the box, you just gotta configure it. You can enable it globally like this:

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Spring Boot's own corsConfigurer should work the same as the CORSFilter I had, right? I added CorsMapping in my Application and still got the same error. Just realize this error may not be what it means. Since I tested the same url in a rest client tester and got 404. It may not be a CORS issue after all. But why 404?

Comment: You probably aren't setting the right context path in tomcat. How are you configuring tomcat?

Comment: I didn't do any config for context path. Everything is default.

Comment: Where is this coming from? ristoreService

Comment: What do you mean? The web service I created was deployed with the name ristoreSerivice.war. I copied the war to webapps dir under tomcat. I don't have a `web.xml`. Could it be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

To solve CORS issue I used [@CrossOrigin](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html). And I did not implement my own CORS filter. Any way spring already have provided few [addition solutions for CORS issue](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).

If you need only your filter you could use it in this way:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(yourFilter);
    ...
}
```